# Prove that a function defined on points in a plane is zero

Tags: geometry, functions, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Let $n\ge3$ be an integer, and $f:P\to\mathbb R$ be a function defined on any point in the plane $P$, with the property that for *any* regular n-gon $<A_1A_2A_3\cdots A_n>$,

$$f(A_1)+f(A_2)+f(A_3)+\cdots+f(A_n) = 0 \quad \forall n\in\mathbb N/\{1,2\}$$

Prove that $f$ is the zero function, i.e, $f(t) = 0 \quad\forall t\in P$.

---

My initial idea was that if I could prove that $f$ is constant, my proof would be complete. I proceeded with my idea like shown in the diagram which I have attached because it is slightly hard to put it into words. Forgive my extremely poor paint skills.

[image]

I label the red points as $A_2$ and $A_3$(which is which doesn't matter), the blue as $A_1$ and the green as $A_4$. $A_1A_2A_3$ and  $A_2A_3A_4$ are supposed to equilateral triangles, (regular 3-gon feels weird)

Now given that $f(A_1)+f(A_2)+f(A_3)=0$ and $f(A_4)+f(A_2)+f(A_3)=0$, we can conclude that $f(A_1)=f(A_4)$. I continue my argument by asserting that this can be done for any two arbitrarily chosen points in the plane by taking $A_2$ and  $A_3$ on the perpendicular bisector of $A_i$ and $A_j$. Thus $f(A)$ is constant for all points on the plane. Thus $f$ is the zero function.

Are there any flaws in my argument? Is this rigorous? Anyone has any better ideas? By better I mean I know I could prove this algebraically, but this geometrical argument (if it is correct) is a lot more elegant than any algebraic argument I can think of, but maybe someone can do even better?

Comment: "I continue my argument by..." you don't need to do that: you could have just fixed $A_1$ and let $A_4$ be any point in $P$, then, as you have done, prove that $f(A_4) = f(A_1)$ for any $A_4 \in P$ and by transitivity of equality deduce that $f$ is costant.

Comment: That only proves it for $n=3$. In the original problem, aren't you fixing the n beforehand?

Comment: Oh well in that case the proof is wrong...

Comment: @dani_s: Seems you are missing the regularity requirement. Your triangles would be non-regular, so the assumption does not apply.

Comment: @blues66 actually no. I proved the function is always zero. The function definition doesn't depend on n. No I am not fixing n before hand. It says the equation holds for all $n$. I am applying the equation(already known to be true) for $n=3$

Comment: @MvG i said choosing $A_2$ and $A_3$ on the perpendicular bisector(at equal distances from the line). that would make $A_1A_2A_3$ regular,right?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: if you are free to choose $n$, then your approach seems sound. You might want to edit the question to clarify that the equation will hold for all $n$. My concern was with the simplification dani_s suggested.

Comment: @MvG okayedited. :)

Comment: @MvG if $A$ and $B$ are points then there always exist $C$ and $D$ such that the triangles $ACD$ and $BCD$ are regular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertices of a regular $n$-gon in argand plane with center $z$ and one of the vertices $z+\omega$, are $\{z+\omega\alpha^j| j=1,\ldots,n \}$ where, $\alpha=\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$.

So, the functon satisfies $\sum\limits_{j=1}^nf(z+\omega\alpha^j)=0$, for arbitrary $z,\omega \in \mathbb{C}$.

In particular replacing $z$ with $z-\omega\alpha^k$, for a fixed $k$ and choosing $\omega=1$ gives us,

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^nf(z-\alpha^k+\alpha^j)=0$

Summing over all $k=1,\ldots ,n$ we have, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^nf(z-\alpha^k+\alpha^j)=0$

or, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{l=1}^nf(z-\alpha^k+\alpha^{k+l})=0$ (where, $j \equiv k+l \mod n $)

Now, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\bigg(\sum\limits_{l=1}^n f(z-\alpha^k+\alpha^{k+l})\bigg) = nf(z) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\bigg(\sum\limits_{l=1}^{n-1} f(z-\alpha^k+\alpha^{k+l})\bigg)$

$= nf(z) + \sum\limits_{l=1}^{n-1}\bigg(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(z-\alpha^k+\alpha^{k+l})\bigg) = nf(z)$

[Since, when $l=n$, $f(z-\alpha^k+\alpha^{k+l})=f(z)$

and for $l\neq n$, $\bigg(\sum\limits_{l=1}^n f(z-\alpha^k+\alpha^{k+l})\bigg)= \bigg(\sum\limits_{l=1}^n f(z-(1-\alpha^{l})\alpha^k)\bigg)=0$]

Thus, $nf(z)=0$, or $f(z)=0$.

Comment: Complex plane, I like this. :D

Comment: I used complex plane ... coz' it makes writing easier ... you can argue geometrically as well :)

Comment: Oh I most definitely prefer complex plane. :) I switch vectors for complex numbers whenever possible.

Comment: @r9m, aren't you implicitly taking $\omega=0$?

Comment: @blues66 take the case $n=3$ and construct the points $z-\alpha^k+\alpha^{k+l}$ as $k$ and $l$ varies over $1,2,3$. I think it will be clear whats happening in that double summation. We are adding functional values $3f(z)$ and two equilateral triangles $[z+1-\alpha,z+\alpha-\alpha^2,z+\alpha^2-1]$ and $[z+1-\alpha^2,z+\alpha-1,z+\alpha^2-\alpha]$ .I wanted to give the geometric counterpart .. but its easier to write it with roots of unity :)

Comment: I mean, when you take $l=n$, you had $\omega=1-\alpha^l\Rightarrow\omega=0$, but $\sum\limits_{j=1}^nf(z+\omega\alpha^j)=0$ doesn't necessarily holds for $\omega=0$.

Comment: @blues66 $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\bigg(\sum\limits_{l=1}^n f(z-\alpha^k+\alpha^{k+l})\bigg) = nf(z) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\bigg(\sum\limits_{l=1}^{n-1} f(z-\alpha^k+\alpha^{k+l})\bigg)$

$ = nf(z) + \sum\limits_{l=1}^{n-1}\bigg(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(z-\alpha^k+\alpha^{k+l})\bigg) = nf(z)$

Comment: @r9m, you're not getting me, I'll try to be clearer.
First, $\sum\limits_{j=1}^nf(z+\omega\alpha^j)=0$ holds $\forall z\in\Bbb C\forall \omega\in\Bbb C-\{0\}$, cause you have n-gons inscripted in a circle of center $z$ and radius $\omega\ne 0$.
Then you work on the equations and we get to the part "The summation ∑l=1n(∑k=1nf(z−(1−αl)αk))=0 (Since, the inner sums adds the functional values at the vertices of the regular polygon with center z and ω=(1−αl), for each l)". But here you're admitting $l=n$, and this makes $\omega=1-\alpha^n=0$. Do you understand my objection?

Comment: @blues66 Edited .. it seems I forgot to add the most crucial point .. thanks a lot :) I guess now I understand what the doubt was :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(O)=\varepsilon$, where O is the origin, and $\varepsilon\neq0$.

Consider the points $A(\cos( \pi/6), \sin( \pi/6))$ and $B(\cos( \pi/6), -\sin (\pi/6))$.  Then OAB is an equilateral triangle so $f(A)+f(B) = -\varepsilon$

Now consider the equilateral triangle ABC, where $C=(2\cos (\pi/6), 0)$.  Hence $f(C)=\varepsilon$.

By similar reasoning, we must have points $D(0, 2\cos (\pi/6)), E(-2\cos (\pi/6), 0), F(0, -2\cos (\pi/6))$ such that $f(D)=f(E)=f(F)=\varepsilon$.

But CDEF is a square, so we have a contradiction.  QED